# Save Logs inside Django container to AWS S3

Tags: django, docker, logging, scrapy

Hey i have a docker Django app deployed on AWS. i am having trouble figuring out a way to store the logs generated inside the container, whenever i build it again the logs are delete. i want to store the logs to S3 maybe using a CRON job.

one thing i can do is

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml exec web tail django.log > django.log
```

this gets the logs out. but there is also a directory that has sub directories that has logs for scrappy. they also need to be stored on s3 once a day.

any guide will help. thanks!

Comment: have you looked at [watchtower](https://pypi.org/project/watchtower/) ? 

You can use that to ship your logs to AWS CloudWatch Logs

Comment: i looked into it, but i do not want to use this approach. i have already generated logs and i want to run a cron job once a day at a specific time to get the logs directory from the container and export the it to s3

Comment: you can find container logs files under /var/lib/docker